# Authentication error after lid reopens

Tags: graphics, suspend, 22.04, authentication

I am currently using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS whenever I reopen the lid after suspending, I get an authentication error and many of the icons disappear. I can only shut down using the power button when this occurs.

[image]

I tried updating all the Nvidia drivers and changing the hard disk, but it still happens. This doesn't occur when using a bootable Pendrive. What could cause this? I am on Asus R558uq model. If you need more information please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing a similar behavior on Fedora 37 with the proprietary Nvidia drivers. After having read several bug reports it seems as if Nvidia's `nvidia-powerd` is causing this.

One possible workaroud might be:

1. Press Ctrl + F3 to switch to another terminal.
2. Login to the console.
3. Restart the `nvidia-powerd` service.
4. Press Ctrl + F2 to switch back to the GUI login.

`sudo systemctl stop nvidia-powerd.service && sudo systemctl start nvidia-powerd.service && systemctl status nvidia-powerd.service`

Comment: Can I know what this does? I am not an expert

Comment: I'm not an expert on this either, but basically it's restarting the system service which is responsible for handling the graphic card's power management. It seems as if there is a bug in this component which can be worked around by restarting.